# Copy multiple files from multiple folder to single folder in Azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a folder structure like this as a source

```
Source/2021/01/01/*.xlsx files
Source/2021/03/02/*.xlsx files
Source/2021/04/03/.*xlsx files
Source/2021/05/04/.*xlsx files
```

I want to drop all these excel files into a different folder called **Output**.
Method 1:
When I am trying this, I used copy activity and I am able to get Files with folder structure( not a requirement) in Output folder. I used Binary file format.
Method 2:
Also, I am able to get files as some random id .xlsx in my output folder. I used Flatten Hierrachy.

My requirement is to get files with the same name as source.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i suggest and I have implemented something in the past and i am pretty confident this should work .

Steps

Use getmetada activity and try to loop through all the folder inside Source/2021/

Use a FE loop and pass the ItemType as folder ( so that you get folder only and NO files , I know at this time you dont; have file )

Inside the IF , add a Execute pipeline activity , they should point to a new pipeline which will take a parameter like
Source/2021/01/01/
Source/2021/03/02/

The new pipeline should have a getmetadata activity and FE loop and this time we will look for files only .

Inside the FE loop add a copy activity and now will have to use the full file name as source name .